# Jquery: Setting permanent height to an specific tab & resize plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with jquery sliding tabs. I have found a resize plugin that helps the tabs adjust to expanding content. The only thing is that i want to set a permanent height to tab 1(st_content_1). The code i have below works but it is a bit faulty.

- Should place in the function if statements?
- Check for the height of the first tab and then set it?
- Or a any better solution?

  You can check my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/slidingtabs/horizontal.html).

Jquery

```
 $('.st_tab_view').resize(function() {
    
    var height = 250
    $('div#st_content_1').css('height', height+'px');

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.st_view').css('height', $this.height());
    
    
    
});
```

Comment: Try not to name variables after reserved words (re: this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a min-height or max-height in the css for .st_content_1 ? especially since height is fixed at 250. so in your css:

```
#st_content_1 {
   min-height: 250px;
}
```

Of course it doesn't work in older IE versions.

Then remove this

```
var height = 250
$('div#st_content_1').css('height', height+'px');
```

Comment: even after you remove those two lines? how so? you are only setting the height of a parent element right? so with min-height set, $this.height() will always be greater than 250

Comment: Yea, I deleted those two lines from the function. As i mentoined I have expanding content. In order for the tab to adapt to expanding content i am using a resize plugin. The issue is that the resize plugin grabs the largest height of x-tab and display it for the first tab and this is why i want to set a permanent height for the first tab.